# Setting array from different class objective-c gives me error but still works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Error tells me that "No '-setRosterForBoat:' method found".

What I am doing is attempting to pass an array backwards through the Navigation Controller  stack that i have.

In the viewContoller that I am attempting to pass the array to I have it set up in the .h like so:

```
NSArray *rosterForBoat;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *rosterForBoat;
```

But the program runs fine and the array gets set with the proper objects. Should I hate to just ignore this, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
   CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:appDelegate.boatNavController.viewControllers];

   [appDelegate.boatNavController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

   [[arr objectAtIndex:1] setRosterForBoat:tempRowers];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the `rosterForBoat` array as property, I would **[synthesize](http://otype.de/index.php?id=106)** it and set it the following way:

```
CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:appDelegate.boatNavController.viewControllers];

ViewController *view_controller = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
[appDelegate.boatNavController popToViewController:view_controller animated:YES];

view_controller.rosterForBoat = tempRowers;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that NSArray doesn't define a type like other language's arrays.  So, when you use objectAtIndex:, it comes back at the generic 'id' type.

If you want to make the warning go away, do something like:

```
    YourViewController * controller = [arr objectAtIndex: 1];
    [controller setRosterForBoat: tempRowers];
```

And make sure that you define setRosterForBoat: in your view controller's .h file.

Edit: And to answer your other question:  it works because Objective-C uses message passing to communicate between instances.  At compile time, XCode can't find Class->Method relationship between 'id' and setRosterForBoat:, but during runtime, because that method happens to exist for your view controller, everything works swimmingly.

Comment: nice addition to my solution...+1